# Func delegate with variable inputs?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, delegates, func

I have a bunch of async methods which all take different inputs, but they all have the same output - an instance of a class named `HttpResponseData` (for example).

Now I want to have an sync method called `RunWithRetry` which takes a `Func` delegate input (and returns `HttpResponseData`) and runs it several times until some condition becomes true, like the example code below:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseData> RunWithRetry(Func<string, int, HttpResponseData> methodToRun,
    string input1, int input2, int maxRetryCount = 10, int retryIntervalDelayInMs = 5000)
{
    //some example usage code below where retry logic runs `methodToRun` as many times as needed

    HttpResponseData responseData = null;
    int triesDone = 0;

    while (triesDone <= maxRetryCount && (responseData == null || responseData.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK))
    {
        if (triesDone > 0)
            Thread.Sleep(retryIntervalDelayInMs);

        responseData = await Task.FromResult(methodToRun(input1, input2));
        triesDone++;
    }
    return responseData;
}
```

Problem is, `Func<string, int, HttpResponseData> methodToRun` defined as input above requires a specific combination of input parameters (in this example: `string, int`). This doesn't work for me because as I said, I have a number of different inputs which all have different inputs but the same output: `Task<HttpResponseData>`. So I don't want to specify different versions of this `RunWithRetry` method with different set of inputs for `methodToRun`.

Is there a way I can define a generic `Func` with specific output but variable/different inputs ?

Comment: Why not just construct the existing `Func` outside of your retry code, and simply pass in `Func<HttpResponseData>` instead?

Comment: @John, can you provide some example code to demonstrate that ?

Comment: But what arguments are you going to pass in each time you call it? Why not just `Func<HttpResponseData>` and force the caller to write a lamda to pass the real arguments `RunWithRetry(() => OtherFunc(a,b,c))`.

Comment: Since signatures are different but output is the same. Is "passing a base data class" and cast it into different signature viable for your case? Like a base `RequestData`, and derived `StringIntRequest`, `IntIntRequest`...etc. Then a strategy lookup for corresponding `Func`.

Comment: What about passing the input parameters encapsulated into a class/struct and then create a generic function? Something like `RunWithRetry<T>(Func<T, HttpResponseData> methodToRun...`

Comment: Important question here would be of the input also differs in amount of parameters? If they are the same amount you could go with generics, otherwise generics won't help. That said the comment from Jeremy Lakeman always works, and would probably be the way I would implement this myself (though there are plenty of libraries for retries I would use before inplementing it myself)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like strategy pattern.

Using generic input to box different arguments and expand arguments in the function.

Following are pseudo code for demonstration.

```
abstract class Request
{
    // type or other base data
}

class StringIntRequest
{
    public string StrData{get;set;}
    public int IntData{get;set;}
}

class IntIntRequest
{
    public int IntData{get;set;}
    public int IntData2{get;set;}
}
// Initial strategies somewhere.
Dictionary<Type,Func> strategies;

public static async Task<HttpResponseData> RunWithRetry( Request req ){
    // ....
    HttpResponseData = strategies[ req.GetType() ]( req );
    // ....

}

// Example for one strategy
public HttpResponseData StrIntStrategy( Request req ){
    StringIntRequest derived = (StrigIntRequest)req;
    // business logic
    return new HttpResponseData( response );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend using Polly, a well-tested and widely-used library for retry logic.

But to answer your original question, what you really want to do is "bind" the parameters to your delegate, and then use the bound delegate. So, instead of defining a method that takes a delegate *and its parameters*, define the method that takes a delegate *already bound to its parameters*.

Like this:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseData> RunWithRetry(Func<HttpResponseData> methodToRun,
    int maxRetryCount = 10, int retryIntervalDelayInMs = 5000)
{
    HttpResponseData responseData = null;
    int triesDone = 0;

    while (triesDone <= maxRetryCount && (responseData == null || responseData.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK))
    {
        if (triesDone > 0)
            Thread.Sleep(retryIntervalDelayInMs);

        responseData = await Task.FromResult(methodToRun());
        triesDone++;
    }
    return responseData;
}
```

Usage is changed to bind the "method to run" method with its parameters, using a lambda expression:

```
// Old usage:
var response = await RunWithRetry(MethodToRun, "input1", 13, 10, 5000);

// New usage:
var response = await RunWithRetry(() => MethodToRun("input1", 13), 10, 5000);
```

On a side note, [`await Task.FromResult` is an antipattern](https://twitter.com/astevecleary/status/1155827537232220161). I assume this is just example code or incomplete code. A proper asynchronous "method to run" would use an [asynchronous delegate type](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html) and look like:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseData> RunWithRetry(Func<Task<HttpResponseData>> methodToRun,
    int maxRetryCount = 10, int retryIntervalDelayInMs = 5000)
{
    HttpResponseData responseData = null;
    int triesDone = 0;

    while (triesDone <= maxRetryCount && (responseData == null || responseData.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK))
    {
        if (triesDone > 0)
            Thread.Sleep(retryIntervalDelayInMs);

        responseData = await methodToRun();
        triesDone++;
    }
    return responseData;
}

// Usage:
var response = await RunWithRetry(() => MethodToRunAsync("input1", 13), 10, 5000);
```